# Standard Hamcrest matcher to check if collection is empty or null?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Is there a shorter version of the following assert statement using **standard** Hamcrest matchers?

```
Collection<Element> collection = ...

assertThat(collection, is(anyOf(nullValue(Collection.class), 
     emptyCollectionOf(Element.class))));
```

I realize there is a way to create a custom matcher, was hoping that maybe there is already something in place that addresses this without any additional code change.

Comment: There is a shorter version, if your code is changed to never return `null` in place of an empty collection.

Answer (score 12):

There is no out-of-the-box solution, and worse, `either()` can't be used due to [this](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/116) bug. So the shortest way is this:

```
assertThat(collection, anyOf(nullValue(), empty()));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to create a custom Hamcrest matcher, which combines already available matches (like `IsNull.nullValue()` and `IsEmptyCollection.empty()`).

But generally speaking an assert should assert for one thing only.
My opinion is that it's not a huge pain to have two matchers in succession and it's more readable later.

Also there's another preferred pattern - when returning a collection, prefer returning empty collection instead of null. The idea is to avoid unnecessary null checks.

Comment: I agree in principle with your second statement. In practice though this combined situation comes up fairly often, so would be nice to have something like emptyOrNull()

Comment: well different approaches are possible - you can always create a custom matcher (as suggested in other answers as well), or just wrap the two assertions in a utility method "nullOrEmpty(testTarget)" and call that in all places needed. In the end of the day - it's just test cases - if it tests the intended functionality - it's good to go. I really don't see a lot of benefit of squashing these two lines in a single assertion.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to write your own Matcher

```
class EmptyOrNull extends BaseMatcher<Collection> {
    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        boolean result = o == null;
        if (o instanceof Collection) {
            result = ((Collection) o).isEmpty();
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String describeMismatch(Object item, Description description) {
        return "not null or empty!";
    }
    public static Matcher<Collection> emptyOrNull() { return new EmptyOrNull(); }
}
```

and then you can use the shorter version.

```
assertThat(collection, emptyOrNull());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple imperative solution using [Assert.fail](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail(java.lang.String)).

```
if (collection != null && !collection.isEmpty()) {
    fail(collection.toString());
}
```